# Error Error: Compile Error: expecting a right parentheses, found ';' at line 7 column 17

Tags: trigger

```
trigger accountTestTrggr on Account (after insert, after update) {
 List<Account> accountsWithContacts = [select id, name, (select id, salutation, description,firstname, lastname, email from Contacts) from Account where Id IN :Trigger.newMap.keySet()];

List<account> accsWithLargeRev=new list<account>();
List<contact> consWithinNJ=new list<contact>();
For(account a: accountsWithContacts){
  if(a.revenue&gt;50000){
  accsWithLargeRev.add(a);
  }
  for(contact con:a.contacts){
  if(con.state==‘NJ’ || con.state==‘New Jersey’){
  consWithinNJ.add(con);
  }
  }
}
System.debug(‘List Of Account With Large Revenuw: ‘+accsWithLargeRev+’; List Of Contacts within NJ: ‘+consWithinNJ);

 List<Contact> contactsToUpdate = new List<Contact>{};
  // For loop to iterate through all the queried Account records
  for(Account a: accountsWithContacts){
     // Use the child relationships dot syntax to access the related Contacts
     for(Contact c: a.Contacts){
      System.debug('Contact Id[' + c.Id + '], FirstName[' + c.firstname + '], LastName[' + c.lastname +']');
      c.Description=c.salutation + ' ' + c.firstName + ' ' + c.lastname;
      contactsToUpdate.add(c);
     }       
   }
          //Now outside the FOR Loop, perform a single Update DML statement.
  update contactsToUpdate;
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to salesforce.stackexchange pradeep. I fixed your code formatting, but generally you'd be expected to add a little more detail to your question. Look here for more details: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: The answer is in the error, it is on line 7,  17th character in. 
It was expecting an Operator and found a ';'

Answer (score 1):

Change your line to this:

```
if(a.revenue>50000){
```